# Is it possible to calculate natural gas (i.e. methane) flow in pipe based on temperature and pressure?

Tags: flow, gas

Given a known pipe diameter, pressure, and temperature, is it possible to calculate the flow rate of natural gas (i.e. methane et al) in the pipe?  To me, this doesn't seem possible without some sort of pressure-differential measurement across a fixed orifice.  Am I right or missing something obvious?

Thanks for insight.

EDIT: here's a [link](https://allsensors.com/engineering-resources/white-papers/pressure-point-11-calculating-flow-rate-from-pressure-measurements) describing the use of pressures to calculate flow, but it also requires a pressure differential.

Comment: It depends to some extent on how "pressure" is measured. If you are measuring pressure at one end of the pipe in units that are relative to pressure at the other end of the pipe, which would give you a pressure differential, and which wouldn't be that unusual to describe as "pressure" when using less than technically precise terminology to describe the available information, then you could. Until reading the body text of your question, that was the sense in which I thought you were using the term. Words are slippery, even when physics is not.

Comment: Not clear why you are asking, if you believe that a pressure difference is required, and the source you found confirms your suspicion. What have you read which suggests otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I definitely agree with you.  You would need some form of additional information to figure that out (and I also agree that a pressure differential would be a good place to start).

Depending on what goes on in either end of the pipe, there could be **no flow** and you could still measure pressure, temperature and diameter of the pipe.  It's not sufficient information to determine the flow of the gas.